# How to split unicode strings character by character in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, split

My website supports a number of Indian languages. The user can change the language dynamically. When user inputs some string value, I have to split the string value into its individual characters. So, I'm looking for a way to write a common function that will work for English and a select set of Indian languages. I have searched across sites, however, there appears to be no common way to handle this requirement. There are language-specific implementations (for example Open-Tamil package for Tamil implements get_letters) but I could not find a common way to split or iterate through the characters in a unicode string taking the graphemes into consideration.

One of the many methods that I've tried:

```
name = u'தமிழ்'
print name
for i in list(name):
  print i

#expected output
தமிழ்
த
மி
ழ்

#actual output
தமிழ்
த
ம
ி
ழ
்

#Here is another an example using another Indian language
name = u'हिंदी'
print name
for i in list(name):
  print i

#expected output
हिंदी
हिं
दी

#actual output
हिंदी
ह
ि  
ं 
द
ी
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to solve this is to group all "L" category characters with their subsequent "M" category characters:

```
>>> regex.findall(ur'\p{L}\p{M}*', name)
[u'\u0ba4', u'\u0bae\u0bbf', u'\u0bb4\u0bcd']
>>> for c in regex.findall(ur'\p{L}\p{M}*', name):
...   print c
... 
த
மி
ழ்
```

[`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)

Comment: Hi, did you mean 'regex' or 're'? I tried 're.findall(ur'\p{L}\p{M}*', name)' and it returned an empty list.

Comment: I meant "regex". Which is why I wrote "regex". And included a link to `regex`.

Comment: As it turns out, I cannot use the `regex` module in my app engine application since `regex` is not pure python but includes `c` extension. Is there an alternative solution to this problem using Python's `re`module or some other means of achieving this?

Comment: You'll have to use `unicodedata.category()` to get the category of each character in turn and group them accordingly.

Comment: While this may work in this particular case, `\X` is the preferred mechanism for pulling out individual grapheme clusters.

Comment: This solution is not correct. It won't work for combined emojis, for example country flags.

Answer (score 12):

To get "user-perceived" characters whatever the language, use `\X` ([eXtended grapheme cluster](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)) regular expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import regex # $ pip install regex

for text in [u'தமிழ்', u'हिंदी']:
    print("\n".join(regex.findall(r'\X', text, regex.U)))
```

#### Output

```
த
மி
ழ்
हिं
दी
```

Answer (score 2):

`uniseg` works really well for this, and [the docs](http://uniseg-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are OK. The other answer to this question works for international Unicode characters, but falls flat if users enter Emoji. The solution below *will* work:

```
>>> emoji = u''
>>> from uniseg.graphemecluster import grapheme_clusters
>>> for c in list(grapheme_clusters(emoji)):
...     print c
...
```

This is from `pip install uniseg==0.7.1`.

Comment: I tested your emoticons using RegEx 2022.3.15 whichs works fine using eXtended Graphemes `\X`. RegEx has evolved I guess.